# Time limit exceeded in C

Tags: c

I did the code for insert the elements in the linked list its working properly.Then i wrote the code for reverse a linked list in groups of given size.My problem is my code takes too much of time for execution because i want to optimize this code.

For ex:

***INPUT***

```
8  //number of elements

1 2 2 4 5 6 7 8  //elements

4  //position to reverse the list elements
```

***OUTPUT***

```
4 2 2 1 8 7 6 5
```

```c
struct node *reverse (struct node *head, int k)
{ 
    int count=0,i=0,j=0,a[1000],start=0,end;
    struct node *temp=head;
    struct node *t=head;
    struct node *tt=head;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        temp=temp->next;
        count++;
    }
    while(count!=0)
    {
    while((k--)&&(t!=NULL))
    {
        a[i++]=t->data;
        t=t->next;
    }
    end=i-1;
    while(start<end)
    {
       int temp=a[start];
       a[start]=a[end];
       a[end]=temp;
       start++;
       end--;
    }
    while(tt->next!=t)
    {
        tt->data=a[j];
        j++;
        tt=tt->next;
    }
    tt->data=a[j];
    count=count-k;
    i=0;
    j=0;
    }
    return head;
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you implement a linked list for what you can store in a simple array? Just store the numbers in an array and reverse slices of the array. `a[1000]` you even store the data in array, reverse it, and then go back into linked list. And why `a[1000]` ? Why not `a[1002]`? Please post MCVE, how is `node` declared? How is the function called? You don't read any input and don't output anything from the code? Please post a full reproducible example that's compilable. .

Comment: The TLE means that, sadly, the solution isn't good enough. Quite often with "online judge" problems, the obvious solution won't be quick enough, and the real problem is to find a good algorithm and to code it efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

The code needed is literally 6!! lines long

Here you have my example

```
#include <stdio.h>

void reverse(int *first, int *last)
{
    int tmp;

    while(first < last)
    {
        tmp = *first;
        *first++ = *last;
        *last-- = tmp;
    }
}


void reverseFromPos(int *arr, size_t len, size_t pos)
{
    reverse(&arr[0], &arr[pos - 1]);
    reverse(&arr[pos], &arr[len -1]);
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8, 9};
    size_t len;

    reverseFromPos(arr, len =sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]), 4);
    for(size_t index = 0; index < len; index++)
        printf("%d ", arr[index]);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```